# Cleaning SQL "Incorrect string value" Error from PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding, iconv

I've seem this question a million times, but everyone seems to want to solve the problem in the database. I do not. I'm getting this error when parsing a large text file, picking out what I need and inserting it into my database. Out of 24 thousand rows or so, 30 or so have invalid characters in them.

Here is an example of the error, followed by the query that caused it:

`[Query Error: Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBC\x89' for column 'company' at row 1]`

`[INSERT INTO mac_address_db_new (hex,company) VALUES('0847D0','Nokia Shanghai Bell Co. Ltd.）')]`

The 'bad' characters in the string I'm inserting are probably not going to make it all the way to your browser, so you likely can't see the character.

But I'm looking for a simpler solution. Is there a way I can filter out these characters in PHP before I try to send them to MySQL? I already filter with the following functions: `trim( )`, `mb_convert_encoding( )` (to UTF-8), `htmlentities( )`, ~ some case-related functions ~, and finally `mysqli_real_escape_string( )`. But still bad characters are getting through. I have no control over the text file input.

Comment: A lot depends on the data's value to the users. Technically, if you read a text file, you have to use the encoding it was written with, and if you store in a database, you have to then use an encoding/collation for a character set that supports the valued characters, and you have to use a database library that supports communicating those characters. If the exact chars are not valued more than similar ones then your technical choices open up. The ['FULLWIDTH RIGHT PARENTHESIS' (U+FF09)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff09/index.htm) showed fine because SO meets our expectations.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a solution. I ditched the `mb_convert_encoding( )` function and instead used `iconv( )`, specifically this:

`$output = iconv( 'UTF-8', "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $input );`

Apparently the "//IGNORE" part is very important. This quietly strips these 'bad' characters out of my string before I send it off to the database.